# CAShapeLayer: Animate the filling of color

Tags: iphone, animation, layer

I am currently using CAShapeLayer to draw a pie chart. One of the requirements is to animate the creation of pie slices. To achieve this I am animating the "strokeEnd" property to animate the drawing of the paths. Is there a way to animate the filling of the color as well?